# dojo lazytreegrid data from server

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I am new to dojo, and I am trying to use lazytreegrid, I found this example code in the documentation

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/grid/LazyTreeGrid.html

But I want to load the tree data from a servlet/portlet/ from java, and child nodes should be lazy loaded. Not able to find any simple example which shows show this can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the example available at http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/grid/LazyTreeGrid.html to make it work with QueryReadStore which fetches data from a backend service in JSON format.

My sample service returns data in the following format:

```
{"identifier":"id","label":"name","items":[{"name":"Africa","id":1,"type":"CONTINENT","population":null,"area":null,"hasChildren":true},{"name":"Asia","id":8,"type":"CONTINENT","population":null,"area":null,"hasChildren":true}]}
```

Note that unlike the ItemFileWriteStore example, the children element are not populated inline.

Now the Web page code :

```
// Dependencies
dojo.require("dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid");
dojo.require("dojox.grid.LazyTreeGridStoreModel");
dojo.require("dojox.data.QueryReadStore");
.
.
.
// Use QueryReadStore instead of ItemFileWriteStore.
// The URL points to a service that returns root nodes of the tree in JSON format.
// When a node is expanded, the same URL gets called with an extra parameter 
// called parentId=<id> where id is identifier of the clicked row. The service
// should return children of the specified id.
var store = new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({url: "./admin/getRootNodes.json",
             requestMethod: "get" });

// hasChildren field in the JSON response should be boolean (true - has children, false otherwise)
var model = new dojox.grid.LazyTreeGridStoreModel({
      store: store,
      serverStore: true,
      childrenAttrs: ['hasChildren']
    });

/* set up layout */
var layout = [
  {name: 'Name', field: 'name', width: '30%'},
  {name: 'Type', field: 'type', width: '30%'},
  {name: 'Area', field: 'area', width: '20%'},
  {name: 'Population', field: 'population', width: '20%'}
];
/* create a new grid: */
var grid = new dojox.grid.LazyTreeGrid({
    id: 'grid',
    treeModel: model,
    structure: layout,
    rowSelector: '20px',
  }, document.createElement('div'));

/* append the new grid to the div */
dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

/* Call startup() to render the grid */
grid.startup();
```

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST:**

Your Servlet has to output something in a json / xml format and provide this as a weburl.

For example the url http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON

outputs:

> {"status":{"message":"Please add a username to each call in order for
>   geonames to be able to identify the calling application and count the
>   credits usage.","value":10}}

Your servlet should have the same behaviour (not the same data of course) when you access the url in your webbrowser.

**NEXT:**

Use the grid with JsonRestStore as a store, not with ItemFileWriteStore. My example uses DataGrid, but LazyTreeGrid should work kind of the same way with the JsonRestStore...

```
require(["dojo/ready","dojo/aspect",'dojo/_base/lang', 'dojo/topic', 'dojox/grid/DataGrid'  ,'dojo/store/JsonRest','dojo/data/ObjectStore'],
  function(ready,aspect,lang,topic, DataGrid, JsonRest,ObjectStore){

    ready(1,function() {

    var store = new JsonRest({  
            target: "http://yourUrl",
            sortParam: "sortby"
      });


    var layout = [[
    {'name': ' ', 'field': 'extension', 'width': '20px',noresize:true} // Adapt field to json data

    ]];

 var dataStore=ObjectStore({objectStore: store});

        var grid = new DataGrid({
            store:dataStore,
            queryTarget:"objectId",
            structure: layout});

    grid.setQuery({objectId:"1"}); // First QUERY !
    grid.placeAt("myDivId");
    grid.startup();

    });

});
```

Comment: I am trying to use the example given here
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/grid/LazyTreeGrid.html 

in the TreeModel section, it says we can use dojox.grid.LazyTreeGridStoreModel, but how to use this is not clear, any suggestions

Comment: I am trying to use it like this

    var dataStore = new QueryReadStore({url: "<portlet:resourceURL/>"});
    var treeModel = new LazyTreeGridStoreModel({store: dataStore, childrenAttrs: ['children'], serverStore: true});

    var grid = new LazyTreeGrid({
    treeModel: treeModel,
    structure: layout,
    autoHeight: 20}, "gridContainerId");
    grid.startup();

but I am getting javascript error in the browser,

Comment: but I am getting javascript error in the browser,
QueryReadStore is not defined

But I can see QueryReadStore js is getting loaded in firebug

Comment: You need to load it in require statement

Comment: I have it like this dojo.require("dojox.data.QueryReadStore");

Comment: I got it working, after I give like this  var dataStore = new dojox.data.QueryReadStore
But when I give the servlet mapping like this, it giving error saying "/servlet/DataHandler" is not found
var dataStore = new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({url: "/servlet/DataHandler"});

Comment: The url has to be acesssible from your browser. There is no host in the url !

Comment: ok, got it working finally, added context path to servlet path

Comment: but, how does this dojox.data.QueryReadStore work, it is appending parameters like start, count, parentId, sort to the url. How does this happen, can we manipulate any of these paramters. I want to pass parentId when I click on some button on the page, and load appropriate data based on parentId.
example:
/servlet/DataHandler?start=0&count=25

Comment: you should ask a new question for that. BUT if you want to know how stuff is working, you should take a look at dojo's API Documentation: https://dojotoolkit.org/api/

Comment: Looked in the documentation, couldn't really find it.

Comment: please take your time to ask a new question based on your new achievements, i don't know whats working and what not and others might know more about the QueryReadStore stuff...